# How do I get the individual parameters from a Mailgun JSON $results when I create a domain

Tags: php, json, mailgun

I've read the related Mailgun JSON submissions, but nothing specifically applies to me.

When I create a Mailgun domain programmatically it returns a JSON variable called `$result`.

When I run the following code I get the following big block of parameters and data.

```
print_r($results)

Mailgun\Model\Domain\CreateResponse Object ( [message:Mailgun\Model\Domain\AbstractDomainResponse:private] => Domain has been created [domain:Mailgun\Model\Domain\AbstractDomainResponse:private] => Mailgun\Model\Domain\Domain Object ( [createdAt:Mailgun\Model\Domain\Domain:private] => DateTimeImmutable Object ( [date] => 2021-12-26 19:46:04.000000 [timezone_type] => 2 [timezone] => GMT ) [smtpLogin:Mailgun\Model\Domain\Domain:private] => postmaster@pewpew.com [name:Mailgun\Model\Domain\Domain:private] => pewpew.com [smtpPassword:Mailgun\Model\Domain\Domain:private] => d9578877fae09f9d3a35ac1caed7904f-1831c31e-0b71565a [wildcard:Mailgun\Model\Domain\Domain:private] => [spamAction:Mailgun\Model\Domain\Domain:private] => disabled [state:Mailgun\Model\Domain\Domain:private] => unverified ) [inboundDnsRecords:Mailgun\Model\Domain\AbstractDomainResponse:private] => Array ( [0] => Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord Object ( [name:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => [type:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => MX [value:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => mxa.mailgun.org [priority:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => 10 [valid:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => unknown [cached:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord Object ( [name:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => [type:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => MX [value:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => mxb.mailgun.org [priority:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => 10 [valid:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => unknown [cached:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => Array ( ) ) ) [outboundDnsRecords:Mailgun\Model\Domain\AbstractDomainResponse:private] => Array ( [0] => Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord Object ( [name:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => pewpew.com [type:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => TXT [value:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all [priority:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => [valid:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => unknown [cached:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord Object ( [name:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => k1._domainkey.pewpew.com [type:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => TXT [value:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCZ7pb/09Yv9q+a4GCP+gzROIa+v7SkACIrdy+OToGkj3Ljqwb4iE/JojypVHzAKWLFugkAsSh+UqM7Xvcv7puNWgtgDWl/qtfeqNwtXv+/YwDDQ6+un7zLtHfxcOXx3Ll5jIiWfhYgPRZIJSkVJCgCppmLPVCt+0Ps34kic5xSlwIDAQAB [priority:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => [valid:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => unknown [cached:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => Array ( ) ) [2] => Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord Object ( [name:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => email.pewpew.com [type:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => CNAME [value:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => mailgun.org [priority:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => [valid:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => unknown [cached:Mailgun\Model\Domain\DnsRecord:private] => Array ( ) ) ) ) 1
```

What I want to be able to do is to get the individual parameters from `$results`, but I haven't been able to do it successfully.

I tried the following code, but that too didn't work.

```
json_decode($result)
```

Then, I tried the following, because I think I want to return an array of parameters.

```
json_decode($result,true)
```

Basically what I am trying to do is take `$results` variable and get the individual parameters in it.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using a mailgun library, which already returns object, so you can just do something like this:

```
echo $results->getMessage();
```

*i dont know the exact function name of 'getMessage' but with good IDE it should hint you with autocompletion...*

This should return:

`"Domain has been created"`

If you could provide bettter `print_r` that is not on one line, but with proper newlines and link to MailGun library, and what stuff you want to read, i can update the answer.